# Python treats "is" to pluralize string literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python version 3.4.3

Python converting string literal to plural.  I cannot figure out how to solve this.

When I enter:

```
>>> x = ("The number % is incorrect" % 8)
>>> x
'The number  8s incorrect'
```

When I try to escape "is" I get an error.

```
>>> x = ("The number % \is incorrect" % 8)
ValueError: unsupported format character '\' (0x5c) at index 13
```

Comment: What do you mean by escaping `is`? `% \ `  is an invalid format character and `% i` isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `'the number %d is incorrect' % 8`

The problem is that python is reading your `%` (with the space, thanks, Ashwini) , and thinking that is your format character.

Comment: Space is actually a valid flag, so `% is` and `%is` are not equivalent: [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Comment: I completely forgot about the 'd' flag.  This did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Just use `format` function instead:

```
x = "The number {} is incorrect".format(8)
```

Comment: The parens are unneccessary, you can just do
`x = "The number {} is incorrect".format(8)`

Comment: Yes, that's true, I was only trying to reflect OP example.

Answer (score 3):

The string:

```
'the number % is incorrect' % 8
```

is actually interpreted as:

```
'the number [% i]s incorrect' % 8
            # ^ conversion specifier
```

and according to the [docs on formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), the specifier `i` is going to get substituted by the integer `8`.

This can easily be mediated by actually providing the specifier right after `%` as in:

```
'the number %i is incorrect' % 8
```